# How to solve Google Datastore n+1 query issue?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Lets say I have a parent/child relationship models with 2 google datastore kinds.

If I query the child table using the parent key, is there any way of also retrieving the fields from the parent table without having to do n+1 queries ?

```
RequestLedger
key | type   | content | sentTimestamp
123   email    <ssd>     10-10-10


ResultLedger
key               | requestLedger            |to            | deliveredTimestamp | bouncedTimestamp | other
123-xxx@xxx.com     key(request_ledger,123)   xxx@xxx.com     10-10-10
```

code

```
var query = ds.createQuery(env.get('GCLOUD_DATASTORE_NAMESPACE'), resultLedgerKind)
.offset(offset)
.limit(max);

if(parentId){
    query = query.filter('requestLedger', ds.key([requestLedgerKind, parentId]));

}


query.run(function(err, entities) {

  callback(err, entities );
});
```

Query above gives me data from the child table and a reference to the parent kind entity but only the key field of the parent. Any easy eay to get everything back in the query at same time?

Comment: So say "2 google datastore kinds", but your example data indicates just a single kind "RequestLedger", although the Key literal uses a different kind "request_ledger" and the code a 3rd "requestLedger". Can you clarify?

Comment: ResultLedger kind has a property called requestLedger which is a parent (i.e. Foreign key) to the RequestLedger kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the lookup method to get multiple entities by their keys in one request. The rest example is [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/lookup) I'm convinced the javascript implementation has a similar implementation.

Note that since api v1 there is a limit of 1000 keys you can get in a single request. This wasn't so in the beta version.

This should bring back your request count if you first get the children and then lookup their respective parent keys.

Comment: thanks, sounds like a reasonable approach as I would ever only have to deliver a page worth of results e.g. 0-100  , 101-200 etc . - so I could get everything in 2 datastore queries